# Is it possible to have a template and add a certain number of view controllers based on an array count in a page control?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

What I have done is put a container view inside a view controller with many objects and embedded a view controller inside the container view. I then have the cardview view controller which is where I have my image, labels, etc. for each page in the pageviewcontroller. I also have instantiated the Page view controller. They are all the same size as the container.  It keeps crashing at this method. To see all the code refer to https://www.veasoftware.com/posts/uipageviewcontroller-in-swift-xcode-62-ios-82-tutorial

```
 func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {



    var vc = viewController as! cardview //crashes here with nothing in the log and it just says Thread 1: EXC_BAD_access code=1

    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int



    if (index == NSNotFound)

    {

        return nil

    }



    index++



    if (index == self.cardnamepage.count)

    {

        return nil

    }



    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)



}
```

Comment: Isn't pageViewController created for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, totally possible. Post what you've tried and describe what's not working. Your question is to general.

Comment: I updated my code @DaveBatton

Comment: Is `cardview` your class name? Are you sure that the viewController is type of cardview class? You can safeguard your code by using optional binding  instead of force unwrapping the viewController.

Comment: http://puu.sh/nlQp7/dd31dbf1ad.png

Answer (score 0):

Your viewController may not be of the type cardview class. Try this code and see if you get the log and the type of the viewController.

```
guard let vc = viewController as? cardview else {
  print("viewController is not of type cardview. Its of type \(viewController.dynamicType)")
  return nil
}

var index = vc.pageIndex as Int
```

Comment: It crashes at the print line with the same error, but the console says vc = projectname.cardview

Comment: Can check what custom class have you specified in the storyboard for the cardview view controller that is used to add as view controllers to the page view controller?

Comment: everything checks out, the custom class in the storyboard is set to cardview, and the storyboard id is correct.

Comment: Can you try `guard let vc = viewController as? projectname.cardview` where `projectname` is the name of your project?

Comment: I figured it out, I had to add `self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as! [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)`